# trend line for a whole group - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, trend

I'm trying to make a trend line for the total of the groups, but it draws a trend line for EACH group. The same code I'm using I put it here (with iris dataset):

```
iris %>%
  mutate(id = as.numeric(rownames(iris))) %>%
  select(id, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length) %>%
  reshape(., direction = "long", varying = names(.)[2:4], v.names = "valor", idvar = c("id"), timevar = "tipo", times= colnames(.[2:4])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=id, y=valor, fill=tipo)) +
  geom_area() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

An image of the output of my dataframe (without `geom_smooth()` line)

[image]

I have tried adding a trend line with:

```
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

But it adds a trend line for each group, when I just need one for the total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `aes` mapping for each individual geom:

```
iris %>%
  mutate(id = rownames(iris)) %>%
  select(id, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length) %>%
  reshape(., direction = "long", varying = names(.)[2:4], v.names = "valor", idvar = c("id"), timevar = "tipo", times= colnames(.[2:4])) %>%
  mutate(id = as.numeric(id)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_area(aes(x=id, y=valor, fill=tipo)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=id, y=valor), method = "lm")
```

(I needed to add an additional mutate to change `id` to numeric to get your code to work)

Comment: It worked!. Can you explain how changes the "r thinking process" when you put aes() in geom_ instead in ggplot() ?

Comment: Putting `aes` in `ggplot` function applies it globally to every `geom` layer.  I view that as more or less a convenience, but really `aes` mapping is a property of the `geom`s.

Comment: thanks!. By the way, I changed the iris code already (changing id to numeric), to make it reproducible.